# Is this the correct definition of functions reflected about the $y$ axis?

Tags: functions

I'm reading a textbook and in it, it says:

[image]

and

[image]

Is this right?

What if $f(x)$ is $x^3$?

$f(2) = 8$
but
$f(-2) = -8$

That doesn't seem like a reflection about the $y$ axis at al, but a reflection about the $y$ and $x$ axis.

Am I misintepreting this?

Comment: That's because your example can be seen as either since $f(-x) = (-x)^3=-x^3 = -f(x)$, this is true about odd functions, meanwhile even functions will look the same. A function which is neither will show a more obvious effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflection of $f(x)=x^3$ is $r(x)=f(-x)=-x^3$, so the reflection of $f(2)=8$ means that you need still to plug $x=-2$ (not $x=2$) into $r(x)$: $r(-2)=8$.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. When you note that $f(-2) = -8$ this means that the new function at $x = 2$ has a value of $-8$. This indeed is what you would expect when you reflect the graph of $x^3$ around the $y$ axis.

It's probably easiest to make sense of the reflected function by plugging in $-x$ directly to obtain the new result and $\textit{then}$ plugging in specific values to examine the behavior. For instance, take the function

$$
f(x) = x^3
$$

Then its reflection about the $y$ axis, which I'll call $g(x)$ is

$$
g(x) = f(-x) = (-x)^3 = -x^3
$$

If you plot the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ you should see that one is just the reflection of the other about the $y$ axis. If you want to plug in numbers by hand, going back to your original example again note that $f(2) = 8$, whereas $g(-2) = 8$. Similarly, $f(-2) = -8$ and $g(2) = -8$. This is exactly what you would expect since these functions are reflections of each other about the $y$ axis.